# How to send data from checkout to Magento2 controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento, controller, magento2

I have a requirement to send data from ajax to controller,

Code as below -
Route xml - Mycompany/RfrShipment/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="rateshop" id="rateshop">
            <module name="Mycompany_RfrShipment"/>
        </route>
        <route id="inbound" frontName="inbound">
            <module name="Mycompany_RfrShipment"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Controller Code** - Mycompany/RfrShipment/Controller/Inbound/Rateshop.php

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\RfrShipment\Controller\Inbound;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;

class Rateshop implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Contex
     */
    private $context;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
     */
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return json
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->context->getRequest()->getParams();    

        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->debug('@@@@@getInboundShipping1  >>> ');

        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $resultJson->setData(['message' => 'Hello world', 'success' => true]);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

**Ajax Call** - Mycompany/RfrShipment/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-service.js

```
/*global define, url*/
define(
    [
    'jquery', // For jQuery Added
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote', // For Quote Added
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
    ],
    function ($, quote, ko, checkoutDataResolver) {
        "use strict";
        var shippingRates = ko.observableArray([]);
        console.log(" >>> zipcode1 >>>");
        return {
            isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        /**
         * Set shipping rates
         *
         * @param ratesData
         */
         setShippingRates: function (ratesData) {
            var address = quote.shippingAddress();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'rfrshipment/inbound/rateshop',
                type: "POST",
                // data: {},
                data: 'city='+address.postcode+'&postcode='+address.postcode+'&region_id='+address.postcode,
                showLoader: true,
                cache: false,
                crossDomain:true,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                   console.log("Success ");
                }
            });


            if (window.isCustomerLoggedIn == true) {
                var address = quote.shippingAddress();

                // you can get zipcode of current shipping address here
                var zipcode = (address.postcode);

                // STOP TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGE FOR DHL IF SG

                shippingRates(ratesData);
                shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);

            } else {
                shippingRates(ratesData);
                shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);

            }
        },

        /**
         * Get shipping rates
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
         getShippingRates: function () {
            return shippingRates;
        }
    };
}
);
```

Please let me know what is wrong with the above code. When I am on checkout it is throwing an error on the console as controller 404  not found.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: change this url from 'rfrshipment/inbound/rateshop' to 'inbound/inbound/rateshop' (pattern : routename/controller/action)